# LuaBind c++ error handler when calling a Lua function

Tags: c++, error-handling, lua, callback, luabind

I am little newbie in C++ scripting but I know some things.
I'm compiling a plugin that use a function to call an Lua callback using the LuaBind, but the client crashes when function doesn't exists on `main.lua`, also I'm trying to add an error handler to that functions... I don't know what I can do to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
{
    try
    {
        luabind::call_function<int>(L, "onServerFrame", elapsedTime);
    }
    catch (luabind::error& e)
    {
        std::string error = lua_tostring(e.state(), -1);
        std::cout << error << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Lua for a beginner to the scripting world. You should look into AngelScript, it's a lot easier to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Thanks to my friend habi.

```
luabind::object func = g[name]; 
if( func ) { if( luabind::type(func) == LUA_TFUNCTION ) luabind::call_function<void>(L,"onServerFrame", elapsedTime);}
```